# Database of Vehicles/License Plates

Tags: data-request

I'm in research of a databases of vehicles with her license plates because I have a project of recognition of license plates but I don't have any idea where I can find this database

Answer (score 4):

How about the following:

- ["Cars From Rear" Images](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/html-files/archive.html)
- [Number Plate Gallery](http://www.numberplates.com/pr-number-plate-gallery.asp?page=511)
- [License Plate Detection, Recognition 
  and Automated Storage](http://www.zemris.fer.hr/projects/LicensePlates/english/baza_slika.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Although this data is very hard to come by as a download, you can access it via an API via such services like http://www.vehicleregistrationapi.com/

Also, license plates are country specific, you do need an API for the country in question.